# IOS swift date picker from two textfields

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am using two textfields to pick date and time from the date picker.  One date picker contains only date another only time. I want to convert that both textfields data into NSDate. I want get time stamp from two textfields data 20-06-2015 04:14 i am getting like this as string. How can i convert in to NSDate and time stamp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast string value to NSDate object like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
let stringToDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(yourStringDate)
```

This is my solution, it works on me.

Comment: var dateString : NSString = NSString(format: "%@ %@", txtRideStartDate.text, txtRideStartTime.text) as String;
//here i am getting 20-05-2015 16:34 from picking two textfields
         var dateFormatterNew = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatterNew.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatterNew.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        var stringToDate: NSDate = dateFormatterNew.dateFromString(dateString as! String)!//crasing here